# having a dynamic image in PHP with GET params appear in <img> tags

Tags: php, get, gd

I understand this question is pretty similar to this question: [Point an <img> tag to a image dynamically generated by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806599/point-an-img-tag-to-a-image-dynamically-generated-by-php)

But in mine I need to send it different GET parameters each time (sometimes it's a certain set of GET params and sometimes it's a completely different set). This solution was unable to fix it: [Point an <img> tag to a image dynamically generated by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806599/point-an-img-tag-to-a-image-dynamically-generated-by-php/806640#806640)

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

GET parameters are just the query strings appended to the end of the URL.  Thus, to set the parameters `foo` and `bar` to `42` and `cubiculum`, respectively, the URL given in the `IMG`'s `SRC` attribute would end with `?foo=42&bar=cubiculum`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the flag [QSA](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) to the RewriteRule to maintain the QUERY_STRING after rewriting the URL

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly legal and should work flawlessly:

```
<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg?get=data" />
```

This keeps the query string intact:

```
RewriteRule (.*).png(.*) $1.php$2
```